# Find if field in one Enumerable exists in two possible fields of another

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have two enumerables made up of different types.

```
public Contact
{
    public string fullName;
}

public Property
{
    public string Rep;
    public string PropMgr;
}
```

I'm trying to get all "Contacts" who are represented in either the Rep or PropMgr fields.

My intuition says join on rep for one result, then join on PropMgr for another result set. Then join the result sets and select distinct. Not sure if that will even work and if it will seems like there is a more efficient way.

---

Adding some additional information:
Some data would be

```
Contact
  FullName: Nick

Property
  Name: "Happy Place"
  PropMgr: Nick
  Rep: Sally
```

When comparing the two sets and I get to this combination, I want to select the contact "Nick".

Keeping in mind I have IEnumerable ContactsList and IEnumerable PropertyList

Comment: You mean where `fullName` value equals `Rep` or `PropMgr` property value?

Comment: Yeah. It could be either

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question,  but doesn't .Where (fullName == Rep | fullName == PropMgr) solves it?

Comment: This would work if I were comparing a single contact to multiple properties. But I'm comparing multiple contacts to multiple properties. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any data to test it, but I guess something like this should work:

```
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = ...
IEnumerable<Property> properties = ...

var query = from property in properties
            from name in new[] { property.Rep, property.PropMgr }
            join contact in contacts on name equals contact.FullName
            select contact;

var result = query.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following Linq Query

```
Contacts.Select(x=>x.fullName).Intersect(Properties.Select (x=>x.Rep).Union(Properties.Select(x=>x.PropMgr))

// contacts -> IEnumerable of Contact, Properties -> IEnumerable of Property
```

Answer (score 0):

So many different ways to solve the same problem...

Something a little lower-tech to try:

```
var namesInProperties = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (Property p in PropertyList)
{
    namesInProperties.Add(p.PropMgr);
    namesInProperties.Add(p.Rep);
}
IEnumerable<Contact> matchingContacts = ContactsList.Where(c => namesInProperties.Contains(c.fullName));
```

Comment: Ugh yeah, you got it too. Thanks for the help!